# SQL Update run Column come back to initial value

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to update a column from a Table with SQL Update query, it gets update and show me the correct value updated when I run the select statement. but after sometime it come back to the initial value. I didn't find any such trigger written which do that, so how this is happening, pls help

```sql
    BEGIN TRAN
    Update Item set Column1='A' where Id=1234
    COMMIT
```

Above query run output-
1 row affected.
I can check that using

```sql
    Select * from Item where Id=1234
```

But after sometime the `Column1` value comes back to it's initial value. How come

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Maybe in other part of your code you are changing the value (accidentally)

Comment: @pringi- SQL server